# Getting last nav element in grid header

Tags: javascript, ag-grid

I have a grid which I need to perform a function when the last element in the navigation has focus. However, I'm having trouble getting my script to find the last element in the row:

```
const cells = document.getElementsByClassName('ag-header-row');
[...cells].map(cell => {
  console.log(cells.length-1);
})
```

The header parent markup:

```
<div class="ag-header-row" role="presentation" style="top: 0px; height: 32px; width: 800px;">
```

with nav item markup:

```
<div class="ag-header-cell ag-header-cell-sortable" role="presentation" col-id="athlete" style="width: 200px; left: 0px;">
```

When the user arrows through the header, and gets to the last header column, I need to fire off an event listener that will set the focus to the first cell in the data grid body below.

Plnkr link: [Link](https://plnkr.co/edit/cgkFVBEpJ9FxZ4jM1iIp?p=preview)

**UPDATE**

I've added a script that is supposed to look for the `focus-visible` class on the header cell as well as if the header cell is the last one on keypress and set the focus to the first cell in the body on arrow right key. However, I've getting the error `headerCells.addEventListener is not a function`. I'm also not sure I have the logic setup correctly to check for the last header cell and/or `focus-visible` class.

```
const headerCells = document.getElementsByClassName('ag-header-cell');
const last_cell = headerCells[headerCells.length-1].attributes[2].value;
const hasFocusVisible = document.querySelector('.ag-header-cell-label').classList.contains('focus-visible');
console.log(hasFocusVisible);
[...headerCells].map(headerCell => {
  console.log(headerCell)
  headerCells.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
    if(e.key === "ArrowRight" && hasFocusVisible == true && last_cell) {
      //if last_cell and 'ag-header-cell-label' has 'focus-visible', set focus to first cell in body
      const bodyCell = document.getElementsByClassName('ag-cell')[0];
    }
  })
});
```

Updated Plnkr link: [Updated link](https://plnkr.co/edit/6VGVV7ekj711iqyafMcA?p=preview)

Comment: You have all this `element.addEventListener` stuff. Is there a reason you aren't really using ag-grid's "keyboard navigation" features? https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-keyboard-navigation/#custom-navigation

Comment: @thirtydot - it doesn't seem to allow arrow key navigation between header cells, nor does it allow access from the header cells to the body cells with the arrow keys.

Comment: I've looked through your last bunch of questions. What's the point of doing this? Is it for accessibility reasons? As an aside, have you considered the effects of the user changing the column order, or hiding columns? You probably can't just throw all this code in `onGridReady`.

Comment: If you look at [the ag-grid pipeline](https://www.ag-grid.com/ag-grid-pipeline/) and search for "AG-1543", you'll see "Allow tab key to navigate through elements in the column header". This is marked as a "Complex Feature Request". You're basically trying to hack on a tricky to implement feature. It's going to be *really* hard to do it right. You might want to file this one under the "too hard to do, let's just wait for ag-grid to eventually do it" category. If you have ag-grid-enterprise, you could try asking the grid authors about this feature request.

Comment: Yes, this is for accessibility. There's currently a backlog of tasks with AG-Grid to do the same thing, but I need to add this functionality asap. Yes, I've considered the the effects of the user modifying the headers (which I'd need to update in componentDidUpdate in some way), but testing this without updating headers.

Comment: @thirtydot - I agree with your previous statement but need to implement this, as I don't really have time to wait for an eventual feature implementation. I've updated the question with new code and plnkr link.

Comment: `addEventListener` only works with a single element, you're trying to apply it to multiple elements. You have `headerCells.addEventListener`, you probably meant `headerCell.addEventListener`. I wish you the best of luck, this is going to be difficult for you.

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to find the last element in a specific selector, try this:

```
var cells =document.querySelectorAll('.ag-header-row');
var last_cell = cells[cells.length-1];
```

Comment: That returns the list of all `ag-header-cell`, not the last element.

Comment: "cells" returns an array, but "last_cell", returns the last element from array. At least, it should.

Comment: It did once, but continues to come up `undefined`.

Comment: If you run console.log(cells.length) and it returns 0, then the selector is wrong. I tried to find your selector, but in the example it runs into an iframe.